# Reading Parentheses and Negation

Tags: parsing, haskell

My goal is to build a calculator in Haskell using Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP, which implements +,-,*,/,^, as well as negation, and follows PEMDAS. First, I have to parse a string input to a mathematical expression (`MathExp`). Part of the code I have is as follows:

```
import Control.Applicative hiding (many)
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import Text.ParserCombinators.Readp
type Name   = String  
type Number = Int    

data MathExp
  = Number Number
  | Neg    MathExp
  | Plus   MathExp MathExp
  | Minus  MathExp MathExp
  | Mult   MathExp MathExp
  | Div    MathExp MathExp
  | Pow    MathExp MathExp
  | Var    String
  deriving (Eq, Show)

parseNumber :: ReadP MathExp
parseNumber = do
  skipSpaces
  x <- munch1 isDigit
  return (Number (read x :: Int))

parsePlus :: ReadP (MathExp -> MathExp -> MathExp)
parsePlus = do
  x <- char '+'
  return Plus

parseMinus :: ReadP (MathExp -> MathExp -> MathExp)
parseMinus = do
  skipSpaces
  x <- char '-'
  return Minus

parsePlusMinus = choice [parsePlus, parseMinus] --parse both--

parseMult :: ReadP (MathExp -> MathExp -> MathExp)
parseMult = do
  x <- char '*'
  return Mult

parseDiv :: ReadP (MathExp -> MathExp -> MathExp)
parseDiv = do
  x <- char '/'
  return Div

parseMultDiv = choice [parseMult, parseDiv] --parse both M,D--
parsePow :: ReadP (MathExp -> MathExp -> MathExp)
parsePow = do
  x <- char '^'
  return Pow

parseNeg :: ReadP MathExp
parseNeg = undefined
parseParens = undefined
```

I have no problem combining the parsers I currently have, using `chainl1` and `chainr1`, to implement associativity and precedence in the right order, but I have no clue how to implement negation and parentheses properly.

What I do know if that negation is also a `-` sign, and it can come before either an integer, parentheses, or a variable (letter string). The variables are another part of the calculator (I'm not having trouble with). Furthermore, a negation can include white-space ; for instance `1+2* -  3` is a valid string input to this calculator.

Comment: "PEMDAS" isn't a real word. Do you mean "the order of operations"?

Comment: Yes, order of operations.

Comment: Hello CS 161 Students Who Found This Page By Searching, 1. Don't post homework online. 2. Don't rely on SO contributors to do your homework for you. If you are having trouble, post on Piazza. That's why we use it. And familiarize yourselves with the collaboration policy: http://cmsc-16100.cs.uchicago.edu/2017/policies.php We will expect any solution you turn in to demonstrate original interaction with the assignment. Email us if you have any questions. Peace, Your Instructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

type Name = String
type Number = Int

data MathExp
    = Number Number
    | Neg    MathExp
    | Plus   MathExp MathExp
    | Minus  MathExp MathExp
    | Mult   MathExp MathExp
    | Div    MathExp MathExp
    | Pow    MathExp MathExp
    | Var    Name
    deriving (Eq, Show)

runParser :: ReadP a -> String -> Maybe a
runParser p s =
    case readP_to_S p s of
        [(x, [])] -> Just x
        _         -> Nothing

mathExp  = mathExp' <* skipSpaces <* eof
mathExp' = term   `chainl1` addop
term     = factor `chainl1` mulop
factor   = expo   `chainr1` expop
expo     = number <|> var <|> parens mathExp' <|> neg expo

number = skipSpaces *> (Number . read <$> munch1 isDigit)
var    = skipSpaces *> (Var <$> munch1 isAlpha)
addop  = skipSpaces *> (Plus <$ char '+' <|> Minus <$ char '-')
mulop  = skipSpaces *> (Mult <$ char '*' <|> Div <$ char '/')
expop  = skipSpaces *> (Pow <$ char '^')
neg p  = skipSpaces *> (Neg <$> (char '-' *> p))

parens = between (skipSpaces *> char '(') (skipSpaces *> char ')')

main = print $ runParser mathExp "1+2* - 3"
```

Output will be:

```
Just (Plus (Number 1) (Mult (Number 2) (Neg (Number 3))))
```

Comment: One more question: If I also wanted to implement a parser that could read the following string: "put (x,y,zee) = (1,2,3) for x+y*zee" with the words "put" and "for" indicating I'm declaring/using variables, and I want this to parse to `["x", "y", "zee"] [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3] (Plus (Var "x) (Mult (Var "y) (Var "zee")))` how would I go about doing this?

Comment: First of all, you have to design Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) for your task with respect to your syntax. Then, you can think about parse of AST. I don't understand syntax and semantic of your example, that's why I can't help you more.